# Scroll indicator to show scroll progress (but don't go back to lower value then current max)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to include a scroll indicator to show "reading progress" on an article.

This is the code that I'm building this on:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp

Right now I haven't got any progress at all on how to complete this. The problem is that I don't want the scroll bar to indicate any lower number than the current max scrolled value, f.e. if the user scroll down 50%, the scroll indicator should be 50%, if the user then go up to 25% scroll, the scroll indicator should stay at 50%.

And also, the scroll indicator should always show 100% if there isn't enough content to indicate any scrollbar at all.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Indicator</h2>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>content...</div>
```

Stylesheet

```
/* Style the header: fixed position (always stay at the top) */
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* The progress container (grey background) */
.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
}

/* The progress bar (scroll indicator) */
.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: #4caf50;
  width: 0%;
}
```

Jquery

```
//When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    function myFunction() {
      var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
      var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
      document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that

```
// Check the file size onLoad
    var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    if(winScroll==height){
        document.getElementById("myBar").style.width =  "100%";
    }
    //Check if user readed before 
    if(localStorage.getItem("latestScrolled")){
       var latestScrolled = localStorage.getItem("latestScrolled");
       document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = latestScrolled + "%";
    }
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    function myFunction() {
      var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
      var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight; 
      var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
      var latestScrolled = localStorage.getItem("latestScrolled");
      if(scrolled < latestScrolled){
            document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = latestScrolled + "%";

      }else{
          document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
          localStorage.setItem("latestScrolled", scrolled);
      }
    }
```

Also working fiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/whatatimetobealive/t90xhak1/21/). Hope it helps...